# How to get Client's IP in Django Views

Tags: django, view

I have piece of code to extract client IP in Django views. However my code is executing only this ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') and I am always getting 127.0.0.1 as IP.
Most of the solutions I have searched used below mentioned code. Any other way to do it??

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

Comment: Try to look into `x_forwarded_for` variable without splitting it. What's in there?

Comment: Hi, here request.META dictionary does not have key as 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', but has key 'REMOTE_ADDR', so my code is going on else part always.

Comment: It seems like you're using ./manage runserver as a server. Is it visible from the Internet? I mean if you connect via http://127.0.0.1:8080 then obviously your IP will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is correct.You are running this in your localhost and accessing from your same system thats why you are getting 127.0.0.1 as client IP. If you need to verify this just try using 'ngork' and check the IP.